# PHP mb_convert_encoding, issue with double decoding

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, mb-convert-encoding, windows-1251

I have some problems with **mb_convert_encoding**. In the database I have table:

- topics (latin1_swedish_ci)

Website is in UTF-8. And db connection to MySQL is in UTF-8 too. I can't change connection settings, but I can change db table.

I was thinking that I can double decode it and get UTF-8. For now it's looks like so:

`string 'ÐšÐ²ÐµÑÑ‚Ñ‹.' (length=27)`

And I've tried next solution:

`mb_convert_encoding($str, 'Windows-1251', 'UTF-8');`

Out:

`string '?????�???�?�.' (length=13)`

Comment: Where is the windows charset coming from? Update the DB table to be UTF8 as well. Use utf8 everywhere and you dont need to change the encodings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: If you think you're going to have `utf-8` character set in your table, change the collation of particular column containing `utf-8` characters to `utf8_general_ci` or make the table itself compatible to `utf8_general_ci` therefore this will reflect on all the columns in the table.

Comment: Do not user `mb_convert...`; two 'wrongs' rarely make a 'right'.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored , especially the part "Test the data".  Let us know the result of `SELECT col, HEX(col) ...` -- we need to know if the text was mangled going into the table or coming out.

Comment: `Кве`, in utf8 (or utf8mb4) is hex `D09AD0B2D0B5`, which is `ÐšÐ²Ðµ` in if Mojibake.  Similarly `ты` comes from `Ñ‚Ñ‹`.  But I don't know about the other two characters in yoru string.  Study this, it may have the answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Comment: You _cannot_ store Cyrillic into a `latin1` column.